# S3 Amazon downloader

Tags: amazon-s3

using ASP.NET MVC 2.0
I am making an amazon S3 downloader.

In download method I prepare a url something like http://s3.amazon.com/mysite.com/image.gif?awsKey=abcde

I redirect the user to that url (which opens that image.gif in the browser)

I see the image opened in the browser , but not as SAVE AS window to save at a location.

I have heard that I can add HEADERS in Response which can force SAVE AS dialog to save the file.

Any idea how those headers re added?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the [Content-Disposition header](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) set to "attachment". However, the webservers serving s3.amazon.com would have to set this header, and changing that is outside of your control.

Comment: You mean we could do that only when we were uploading because i guess Amazon allow that while uploading. Once they are settled, any simple hyperlink redirect will open save as dialog. Nothing fancy should be done on MY Server side code; right?

I guess we cannot do anything there. One idea is to load images in memory save as to my server and provide a download as stream; only in the case of images. But in case of large files or zips I can redirect them to s3, they will see a save as dialog automatically by amazon because their content type is not image.